# onKeyUp event to not execute function after user enters decimal

Tags: javascript

I have an onKeyUp event that calls a function which inserts a decimal place when the user types in 3 or more numbers and sets the value to 2 decimal places.

e.g. user types 123 --> 1.23; user types 1234 --> 12.34

This is the function:

```
function insertDecimal(x) {
    if (x.length > 2) {
        x = x.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g,'');
        var xx = x.substring(0,x.length-2) + "." + x.substring(x.length - 2,x.length);
        }
    else {
        var xx = x;
        }
    return xx;
        }
```

That's okay as far as it goes. But I want to trap the the decimal point when the manually user types it in. e.g.

Item is $10.99
User keys 1099 gets 10.99

Item is $10.999
User keys 10.999 gets 10.999

Item is $10.00
User keys 10. gets 10

I can trap the user's decimal in the event handler:

```
var keycode = event.keyCode;
if (keycode != 110){
    insertDecimal(someUserKeyValue);
    }
```

But when the user next presses a number the function kicks back in and executes which is not what I want. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you attach the handler on `onchange`? So the processing of input is easier because the user already typed in his desired input.

examine this scenario:
User want's to input 100.30, so he typed in `100.30`. On your implementation the moment the user hit the second zero the value of the textbox will change to `10.0`, if that's what happened, how are you gonna implement the decimal functionality, if the user's next input is the decimal `.` itself? Well, unless of course you have a requirement that the user can only type 2-digit whole number and any number of digits as decimal places (`xx.xxxxxx`)

Comment: Maybe that's what I have to do. Seems like there must be a better solution though.